# Extra file created while executing a python script

Tags: python, linux

After I execute my python script in linux and then see the contents of the directory, there is another file created with '~' at the end of the file name.What is that file exactly?
P.S-I just started learning python today so I am a complete noob!

Comment: What text editor are you using? It's probably a backup created by it. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173151/what-does-the-tilde-at-the-end-of-a-file-name-stand-for

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I got the required answer.

Comment: @Aditya you may wish to mark the answer as the correct answer for this question, then.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a backup created by your text editor. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173151/what-does-the-tilde-at-the-end-of-a-file-name-stand-for).

> If a file is appended with a tilde~, it only means that it is a backup created by a text editor or similar program; it does not suggest another program is writing to that file.